# Bootstrap with glyphicon in view breaking design

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a view that I am using to display people that have chosen to have a lunch (Mittagessen) or/and a snack (Jause). I want to display a tick (glyphicon-ok) if they have selected either one of the options. Previously I just displayed "Yes" - this was centered and looked fine in the view. As soon as I use the glyphicons the values are no longer centered, they are not in their respective columns (when both are selected) and the separating line is missing (that is not a mistake in the screenshot).

[image]

This is the code I am using for the view column values:

```
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="Jause" id="viewColumn6" style="width:8%;text-align:center" displayAs="hidden">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Jause" xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader6"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
            </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:var idx = viewEntry.getColumnValues().get(6);
        if (idx == 1) {
            return "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
       }}]]></xp:this.styleClass></xp:viewColumn>
```

I am assuming that the problem is that I am hiding the value of the column.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how would this be done correctly using Bootstrap and the extlib? I did take a look at the examples in the ExtLib but couldn't find one in the ToDo.nsf app.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the styling of the column cell itself but insert some HTML with a xp:text element:

```
<xp:text escape="false" styleClass="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'/>"}]]></xp:this.value>
<xp:this.rendered>
return viewEntry.getColumnValues().get(6) == 1
</xp:this.rendered>
</xp:text>&#160;
```

The `&#160;` at the end makes sure the cell is displayed and rendered even when the text (HTML) is not.

Comment: Exactly! You must render the "container" and only show/hide the value inside the container to maintain the layout :-)

Comment: I did try adding your code in the xp:viewColumn after the xp:viewColumHeader but its not working for me... I cannot find the way to add the code in the comments????

Comment: Ah sorry... I was thinking of a repeat control instead of a view. I'd strongly recommend you to use a repeat control except if you need categories.

Comment: `<xp:viewColumn columnName="Jause" id="viewColumn6" style="width:8%;text-align:center">
    <xp:this.facets>
     <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Jause" xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader6"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:text escape="false" styleClass="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
     <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'/>"}]]></xp:this.value>
     <xp:this.rendered>
      return viewEntry.getColumnValues().get(6) == 1
     </xp:this.rendered>
    </xp:text>
    &#160;
   </xp:viewColumn>
`

Comment: @oliver - Yip, currently it is categorised... maybe I could get away with doing it with a repeat control though! I'll give it a try and report back here